# How can I align the center of the eyeballs?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to fix the small dot on the left to the center of the eyeball. I will do this to properly export the rotations of the eyes.

[image]

Comment: the small dot is the origin, in Edit mode select the vertex you're talking about, press Shift S > Cursor to Selected, then back to Object mode, right click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor should work

Comment: Your method works, but after this process I have to click on the eyeballs and use the Apply All Transforms option. This time, the size of the eyeballs becomes very large.

Comment: maybe take a look at the Properties panel > Object > Transform > Delta Transforms and make sure they are set at their default values?

Comment: Now the eyeballs are working the way I want. I reopened my Blender file and applied the Apply All Transform option to the eyeballs first. Then I changed the center of the eyeballs.  Problem solved. Thanks.